# Need Advice: Java Anti If Statement Anti Loops

Tags: java, if-statement

This is only my third program in java. I'm stuck on this part of the problem.

"The formula is not valid if T > 50 in absolute value or if v > 120 or < 3"

I'm not sure how to translate this into code while restricted to use the following:
no, if statements
no, loops
no, importing
no, new classes to be added

Thank you!

Comment: Make a method that uses `&&` statements, and returns a `boolean`

Comment: && won't work || is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean validateFormula(int T, int v) {
    return !(abs(T)>50 || v > 120 || v < 3);
}
```

Comment: It's best not to do other people's homework--rather provide information or hints. Handing out answers is the last resort, not the first.

Comment: Sure @DaveNewton, will keep this in mind from next time.

Comment: True I'm looking to understand. Especially that I saw some anti if statement movements. I was curious but wasn't sure what to look up.
Since its only the third program. We were told to assume the input is already in range.  So I asked for my own sanity. I don't think the default assumption should be that its HW.

Comment: In fact, this is a code-only answer, one that is guaranteed not to help future visitors looking for a similar problem. Not good -1

Answer (score 0):

In giving you a direct answer to this problem, you might not be able to replicate it next time, or to be able to think for yourself.
In `import java.util.*` , `Math.abs(int n)` will return the absolute value of n. The `||` operator means 'or'. I will not assume that you know the basic structure of an if loop so here:

```
    if(condition || condition || condition){
       //execute code here
}
```

You have everything that you need to solve this, good luck. Furthermore, if you do have any more simple questions like this, I would suggest doing a google search instead.